# updating multiple fields depending their old values

Tags: mysql

I've tested this query (see below) and it's not working

I have this Table:

```
id     A      B      C
-----------------------
1      1      2     
2             3     
3      2             4
4      6      2      1
-----------------------
```

I'd like to set A, B or C to 4 in the first empty field, unless 4 is already in A, B or C.

So if **(condition 1)** A!=4 and B!=4 and C!=4 => **(condition 2)** if A!="" goto B, if B!="" goto C, if C!="" skip the update.

```
In my example 
row 1: C => 4
row 2: A => 4
row 3: not updated (4 allready exists)
row 4: not updated (no empty field)
```

The query I came up with:

```
UPDATE table SET 
    A=IF(A!="",A,4),                 //1:
    B=IF(A="" OR B!="",B,4),         //2:
    C=IF(A="" OR B="",C,4)           //3:
WHERE (A!="" OR B!="" OR C!="")      //4:
       AND (A!=4 AND B!=4 AND C!=4)  //5: 

       // 1: if A="", make it 4, else keep value  
       // 2: if A was "" it should be 4 by now, let B be B, else make B 4
       // 3: if A was "" or B was "", one of them should be 4 by now, else make C 4
       // 4: eliminates row 4 (check if there's a free field)
       // 5: eliminates row 3 (condition 1)
```

Whether this query works (especially part 2 and 3) depends on what mySQL does: will it look at the **OLD** values of the fields in the IF statement, or will it first update one field and then take the new value to the next part? A test rum failed, it updated all empty fields to 4, suggesting it takes the new values in account.

So my question: what can I do to make the query meet my conditions?

**[EDIT]**

Not the most elegant query, but this works:

```
UPDATE table SET 
    A=IF( A<>"",A,4),                
    B=IF( (A="" OR A=4) OR B<>"",B,4),        
    C=IF( (A="" OR A=4) OR (B="" OR B=4) OR C<>"",C,4)         
WHERE (A!="" OR B!="" OR C!="")     
       AND (A!=4 AND B!=4 AND C!=4)
```

It seems mySQL takes the new value of A to the IF statement of B, and the new values of A and B to C

Comment: what happens if both A and B are null, and C is not 4?

Comment: in that case it should update A to 4 and leave B alone

Answer (score 1):

try

```
UPDATE table SET 
    A=IF(A is null,4,A),   -- if a is null, set it to 4            
    B=IF(A is not null and b is null,4,B),       -- if A did not meet the condition to set to 4 but B is null, set B to 4
    C=IF(A is not null and B is not null and C is null ,4,C) --  if A or B did not meet the condition to be set to 4 and C is null, set c to 4
WHERE (a+b+c is null)     --- short of "a is null or b is null or c is null"
       AND (A!=4 AND B!=4 AND C!=4)
```

Comment: It's not working. It still is putting `4` in all the empty fields, not in only one.

Comment: works for me. I am guessing you have a problem with the null values you have. Are they empty strings, or nulls?

Comment: They are empty strings, not `NULL`.

Comment: I've updated my question. Somehow adding `OR A=4` and `OR b=4` did the trick for me. Thanks for your support!

Comment: pretty strange, but if it works, it works :) I tried with nulls, not with empty strings, as it's better to have default null on int for latter usability and maintainability.